# Hiding one's actions out of concern for offending others

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was recently on an airplane reading *Why I Am Not a Christian and Other Essays on Religion*, by Bertrand Russell. I was concerned about how other passengers might feel if they saw me reading a book with such a title. So I tried to make sure no one could see exactly what I was reading. Is there a single word or short phrase that describes my hiding something out of concern for offending others? I haven't been able to come up with a word or short phrase that really works.

Comment: I suggest carrying *What Do You Care What Other People Think?* by Richard Feynman

Comment: @deadrat Love those books.

Comment: What reaction are you afraid of? "This guy is not a Christian" - wrong inference. "This guy is interested in religion" - why shouldn't he be? "This guy has an open mind" - well, why not? "This guy is trying to impress other passengers" - well, does it matter?

Comment: You were protecting yourself.  You were keeping something to yourself out of self-protection.

Comment: @aparente001 You're onto something there.

Answer (score 5):

> **discreet**
>   *adjective*
>    careful not to cause embarrassment or attract too
>   much attention, especially by keeping something secret:
>   *The family
>   made discreet enquiries about his background.*
>   *They are very good
>   assistants, very discreet - they wouldn't go talking to the press.*
>   -[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discreet)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a phrase *solicitous discretion*

> [solicitous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/solicitous): characterized by or showing interest or concern:
>
> *she was always solicitous about the welfare of her students*
>
> *a solicitous inquiry*
>
> [discretion:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/discretion) the quality of behaving or speaking in such a way as to avoid causing offense or revealing private information:
>
> *she knew she could rely on his discretion*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 3):

I like discretion (which is perfectly accurate), but given your location where sensitivities can run higher than most I'd offer

Situational awareness.

Answer (score 0):

You may have just been ***self-conscious*** then.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-conscious):

> **self-conscious**
>   *adjective* ​ nervous or uncomfortable because you are worried about what people think about you or your actions:
>
> He looked uncomfortable, like a self-conscious adolescent.
>
> I always feel a bit self-conscious in a hat.
>
> Stop staring - you make me self-conscious.

Answer (score 0):

You were [**cautious**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cautious) not to set of peoples sensibilities. One might even say you put on the [**kid-gloves**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kid-gloves#kid-gloves__2) to handle the situation with potential hostilities in a confined space. You were doing this out of [**prudence**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prudence#prudence__2). It was a [**tactful**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tactful#tactful__5) move on your part.

> ***cautious** ADJECTIVE 1 (Of a person)* careful to avoid potential problems or dangers:
>
> ***kid gloves**, phrase:* handle (or treat) someone/thing with kid gloves:
> *Deal with someone or something very carefully or tactfully*
>
> ***prudence** NOUN [MASS NOUN]* The quality of being prudent; cautiousness
>
> ***tactful** ADJECTIVE* Having or showing skill and sensitivity in dealing with others or with difficult issues

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the individual wanted to simply read her book and avoid confrontation with individuals who may feel passionately about the topic of Christianity and want to engage in conversations about the topic.

The word to use would be "Private".